# Angular 2 Pass Enum to Components Function from HTML

Tags: enums, typescript, angular

I have created an enum to open up a modal based on whether its an add or an edit modal.

```
enum ModalTypes {
    Add,
    Edit
}

public openManageModal(type: ModalTypes) {
    if (type == ModalTypes.Add) {
        //Open edit modal
    }
    else {
        //Open add modal
    }
}
```

I cant seem to figure out how to call this from HTML.  I have tried various things such as openManageModal('Add'), but nothing seems to work.  Clearly I can create a function in the component, and parse the string to an enum, but I think this way would be more appropriate.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call the function like this:

```
openManageModal(0) // for ModalTypes.Add
openManageModal(1) // for ModalTypes.Edit
```

The `enum` declaration will transpile to the following by the TypeScript compiler:

```
var ModalTypes;
(function (ModalTypes) {
    ModalTypes[ModalTypes["Add"] = 0] = "Add";
    ModalTypes[ModalTypes["Edit"] = 1] = "Edit";
})(ModalTypes || (ModalTypes = {}));
```

So it basically creates an object which looks like this:

```
{
    0: "Add",
    1: "Edit",
    Add: 0,
    Edit: 1
}
```

So as you can see `ModalTypes.Add == 0` and `ModalTypes.Edit == 1`.

Comment: Yep! That worked like a charm.  Thanks.  I wish there was a way to reference by name instead of int.  This works for me though.

Comment: @aoakeson, I think you're much better off using strings:  `openManageModal('add')` and `if(type === 'add') {...}`.

Comment: I agree with @aoakeson, it would be nice to reference by name. Using strings is obviously a clearer workaround, but misses the point of using an enum.